# Get Data from Mysql Database to array in C# array out of bounds

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays

I connect mysql database, then I get the x row. And when I try to the push the array the system got error. I dont understand this problem.

I tried this code. But I got error like array out of bonds...

```
int uz = b();// this func. get row number on the table
int[] userData = new int[uz];
MySqlConnection bag = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select readerid From readers",bag);
bag.Open();
MySqlDataReader oku = cmd.ExecuteReader();
oku.Read();
for (int i = 0; i <= uz; i++) {
     userData[i] = Convert.ToInt32(oku[i]);
     listBox1.Items.Add(userData[i]);
}
bag.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use i < uz instead of i <= uz.

for (int i = 0; i < uz; i++)

**EDIT:**
Based on your comment I think you can try this:

```
    List<int> userData = new List<int>();
    MySqlConnection bag = new MySqlConnection(connstring);

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select readerid From readers",bag);

    bag.Open();
    MySqlDataReader oku = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (oku.Read())
    {
    int current = Convert.ToInt32(oku["readerid"]);
    userData.Add(current);

    listBox1.Items.Add(current);
    }
```

Dont forget to close the connections after you dont need them.

Comment: didn't work this solution... i had already try for (int i = 0; i < uz; i++)

Comment: I never used the MySqlDataReader, does it provide a count() or Lenght method that you could use instead of b()/uz?
Like oku.length or oku.count

Comment: this is the b func. ; and i see the uz value true (3);


string commandLine = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM readers";

            using (MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;database=customercardreader;user=root;password="))
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(commandLine, connect))
            {
                connect.Open();
                return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            }

Comment: I think you could wirte it simpler, I will make an edit to my answer.

Comment: Let me know how it went.

Comment: i have already try your edit code but "you have specified an invalid column ordinal" error the system. :(

Comment: oh, maybe I remmeber it wrong, try to change 
int current = Convert.ToInt32(oku.GetString(0)); // from 1 to 0
Or 
int current = Convert.ToInt32(oku["readerid"];

Comment: how do i get array userData value

Comment: You can convert it in to an array if thats easier for you: userData.ToArray();
or you can go:
foreach(int a in userData)
{ /*THE VALUE IS IN a*/}

Comment: thnx again. i'm so haapyy because of you :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the main problem is that you believed `oku[i]` would give you data from the row at index `i`. What it really does is give you data from the **column** at index `i` for the current row. However, there were several other issues with the original code as well.

This should point you in a better direction:

```
var userData = new List<int>();
using (var bag = new MySqlConnection(connstring))
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select readerid From readers",bag))
{
    bag.Open();
    using (MySqlDataReader oku = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (oku.Read())
        {
            userData.Add(oku[0]);
            //userData.Add(oku["readerid"]); //would also work
        }
    }
}
```